# Dropdown menu inside another dropdown menu

Tags: bootstrapper

I have a problem. I want to create an Our Pick dropdown menu inside the Games dropdown menu but I don't why the code doesn't work. Can you guys tell me where is the problem come from?

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Games</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu games-menu" >
                                <li><a href="latest.html" class="dropdown-item">Latest</a></li>
                                <li><a href="best_selling.html" class="dropdown-item">Best Selling</a></li>
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Our Pick</a></li>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu games-menu">
                                            <li><a href="2019.html" class="dropdown-item">2019</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="2020.html" class="dropdown-item">2020</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                </div>   
                            </ul>
                    </li>
          </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It is already inside the games dropdown . what is the problem you are having

Comment: I want to make Our Pick dropdown menu with 2020, 2019 are items inside it. Our Pick you said is just one of the dropdown items of the Games dropdown menu

Comment: you want **another** menu inside our pick menu ?

Comment: I want another menu with 2019, 2020 as items inside our pick

Comment: I followed exactly the steps as when I create the dropdown menu for Games but it didn't work

Comment: have you seen my answer below ?

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: It didn't work as when I hover the mouse or even click on Our Pick, the menu doesn't show up

Comment: All drop downs are working perfectly in my answer. Please check again. Copy the exact same code to what I have provided - let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221483/discussion-between-alwayshelping-and-quang-nguyen).

Comment: Sorry that's my bad, I forgot to put the submenu( 2020, 2019) inside the <li> of the Our Pick

Comment: But I don't understand why I have to place the submenu (2020, 2019) inside the <li> of the Our Pick?

Comment: You can place it outside the our pick as well but as a best practice its ideal to keep toghther to where they belong. If we put outside then you we need to change the CSS as little but as well. Also, if we put outside then the menu will not show a nested (children) - our pick two will show up as normal menu like its will not show up a tree of menu. So ideally adding into `li` is the best practice here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add another nested `li` with another `dropdown` inside it and use custom CSS to display that `dropdown` on hover.

**Live Working Demo:**

```css
.sub-menu:hover .games-menu {
  display: block;
}

.sub-menu2:hover .our-pick-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="navbar-collapse" id="menu">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Games</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu games-menu">
        <li><a href="latest.html" class="dropdown-item">Latest</a></li>
        <li><a href="best_selling.html" class="dropdown-item">Best Selling</a></li>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <li class="sub-menu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Our Pick</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu games-menu">
              <li><a href="2019.html" class="dropdown-item">2019</a></li>
              <li><a href="2020.html" class="dropdown-item">2020</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown">
                <li class="sub-menu2"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle our-pick-2" data-toggle="dropdown">Our Pick 2</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu our-pick-menu">
                    <li><a href="2019.html" class="dropdown-item">2021</a></li>
                    <li><a href="2020.html" class="dropdown-item">2022</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </div>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </div>

      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```